# Interchanging limit and integral symbols without dominated convergence theorem

Tags: integration, limits

How to show that
$$ \int_0^1 \left\vert 1- \frac{\mathrm e^{-h(1+s^2)}-1}{-h(1+s^2)} \right\vert \mathbf ds \xrightarrow[h\to 0]{} 0$$
without using dominated convergence theorem? Does exists an "epsilon" proof or other elementary proof?

Thanks for any answers...

Comment: $ h \longmapsto 1- \frac{\mathrm e^{-h(1+s^2)}-1}{-h(1+s^2)} $ is continuous on $[0,1]$ as $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x- 1}{x} = 1$. Therefore consider $x_n \longrightarrow 0$ and use the uniform convergence of $$ f_n \longmapsto 1- \frac{\mathrm e^{-x_n(1+s^2)}-1}{-x_n(1+s^2)}$$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Observe
\begin{align}
1-\frac{1-e^{-h(1+s^2)}}{h(1+s^2)}= \frac{h(1+s^2)-1+e^{-h(1+s^2)}}{h(1+s^2)}.
\end{align}
Using Lagrange remainder theorem(or Taylor Expansion), we see that
\begin{align}
e^{-x} =1-x+ e^{-\xi(x)}\frac{x^2}{2!} <1-x+\frac{x^2}{2}. 
\end{align}
where $0<\xi(x)<x$.
Thus, it follows
\begin{align}
\frac{h(1+s^2)-1+e^{-h(1+s^2)}}{h(1+s^2)}<\frac{1}{2}h(1+s^2).
\end{align}